# CAN communication between mcp2551 & tja1050 transceivers

Tags: arduino, can

I am trying to have 2 arduinos one connected to mcp2515(controller)& mcp2551(transceiver) , the other is mcp2515(controller) & tja1050(transceiver). I tested the setup by sending CAN messages from one arduino to other. But the message stopped sending after I received 3 messages! Can anyone please help ? Is there any problem connecting 2 different transceivers to communicate on different ends?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question, please provide more details. The most common issues are listed here: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Answer (score 1):

3 messages is exactly the number of transmit buffers in MCP2515. Make sure you are not trying to send messages faster than they can leave the buffers. Depending on a driver you may get no errors and lost messages or get into blocking call or even force the controller chip into error or bus-off state.

The transceivers are compatible so there should not be any problem with them. Make sure you have correct (5V) supply and termination, as well as ground connection between the two.

Comment: Thank you so much , Will try all these. I am using CAN bus shield driver provided by seed studio